# issue scraping all Row Data with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

relatively new to BS4 here

I have the following HTML (truncated for brevity and the URLs Psuedo):

```
    <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th >Part1</th>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://somewebpage.com">87</a>
</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://somewebpage.com">7</a>
                </td>
                <th>Part2</th>
                <td>
                  <a href="http://somewebpage.com"">68</a>
                </td>........
```

using the following:

```
`soup=BeautifulSoup(page['content'], "html.parser")
 table = soup.find("table")
 table_data = [[cell.text for cell in row("td")]
 for row in table("tr")]
 pprint(table_data) `
```

table_data looks like this:

```
    [[],
 [u'87', u'7'],
 [u'68'],
```

how do I get the 'Part1' and 'Part2'  to appear in the same list??

sorry for the troubles ;-)

Expected Output:

```
[[],
     [u'Part1',u'87', u'7'],
     [u'Part2',  u'68'],
```

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45037330/edit) link on your question to add the expected output

Comment: Use this: `row(["td", "th"])`

Comment: Thanks, however I was looking for the following output (it would have helped if I added first time, sorry)

Comment: @MattA please share complete table structure. or at least a few table rows. `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

your table is not structured correctly. Structure your table correctly by following this format: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Imagine if your table was structured like this:

```
content = """<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td>Sum</td>
     <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>February</td>
     <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")

print([header.text for header in soup.find("table").find("thead").find_all("th")])

for row in soup.find("table").find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    print([data.text for data in row.find_all("td")])

print([footer.text for footer in soup.find("table").find("tfoot").find_all("td")])
```

output

```
['Month', 'Savings']
['January', '$100']
['February', '$80']
['Sum', '$180']
```

Comment: Hi, I am not in control of the way the table is structured

Answer (score 0):

If your 'table data looks like this:' section is your desired values, and you simply want to 'flatten' the lists, try:

```
2d_list = [[], [u'87', u'7'], [u'68']]

1d_list = [x for y in 2d_list for x in y]
```

Resulting in: `[u'87, u'7', u'68']`

Comment: i was looking to acheicve: ['Part1',u'87',u'7',u'68'],['part2',u'68']......